# get livescore beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get live score (blue color text) text in below site

http://free.thscore.cc/asianbookie.htm

i wrote following code to get html printed. but blue color text is not there. help me to get blue color score.

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`
`import urllib2`
`import urllib`

`import requests`

`r  = requests.get("http://free.thscore.cc/asianbookie.htm")`

`data = r.text`

`soup = BeautifulSoup(data)`

`print(soup)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source there is a CSS `class="blue"` applied to the html element.

There is nothing intrinsic in the HTML that determines colour.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this ? i am new to beautifulsoup

Comment: more than likely there is a separate stylesheet that sets the text colour using the css class 'blue'. It's not really anything to do with beautiful soup